# POST API in Perl using LWP::UserAgent with authentication

Tags: perl, http, lwp

I am trying to use POST method in perl to send information to an API.

I would like to call the below api which requires following inputs:
URI: https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/SubmitTrade

Input Parameters are:-

Market: The market symbol of the trade e.g. 'DOT/BTC' (not required if 'TradePairId' supplied)

TradePairId: The Cryptopia tradepair identifier of trade e.g. '100' (not required if 'Market' supplied)

Type: the type of trade e.g. 'Buy' or 'Sell'

Rate: the rate or price to pay for the coins e.g. 0.00000034

Amount: the amount of coins to buy e.g. 123.00000000

Please can you tell me how I can call this api from perl ?
Request Structure:

REQUEST_SIGNATURE: API_KEY + "POST" + URI + NONCE + HASHED_POST_PARAMS

API_KEY: Your Cryptopia api key

URI: the request uri. e.g. https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/SubmitTrade

HASHED_POST_PARAMS: Base64 encoded MD5 hash of the post parameters

NONCE: unique indicator for each request.

So question is how do I join this api https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/SubmitTrade and pass the arguments to it with authentication and check if returned result is success?

Result Example:

```
{
    "Success":true,
    "Error":null,
    "Data":
          {
             "OrderId": 23467,
             "FilledOrders": [44310,44311]
          }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Cryptopia account to test this, but this might at least get you closer to a working prototype.

### Setup

Load the required modules and create a `LWP::UserAgent` object.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256);
use MIME::Base64;
use URI::Encode qw(uri_encode);

my $api_key = 'PUBLIC KEY';
my $api_private_key = 'PRIVATE KEY';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
```

### Generating the request

The tricky part is generating the authorization header. The API keys for your account will be base64-encoded - hence the call to `decode_base64()` when using it to sign the request.

```
my $url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetTradeHistory";

my %req = (
    Market => 'DOT/BTC',
);

my $nonce = int(rand(1000000));
my $post_data = encode_json(\%req);
my $post_data_enc = encode_base64(md5($post_data), "");
my $encoded_url = lc(uri_encode($url, encode_reserved => 1));
my $req_signature = sprintf("%sPOST%s%s%s", $api_key, $encoded_url, $nonce, $post_data_enc);
# Sign request signature with private key.
my $req_signature_hmac = encode_base64(hmac_sha256($req_signature, decode_base64($api_private_key)));
# Generate value for 'Authorization' header field.
my $auth_header_value = sprintf("amx %s:%s:%s", $api_key, $req_signature_hmac, $nonce);
```

Notes ...

- An empty string is passed as the second argument to `encode_base64()` - to prevent it from appending a new-line to the output.
- `uri_encode()` from the `URI::Encode` module is used the encode the URL.
- You might want to use an alternative source or random generator for the nonce.

## Sending the request

You could create a `HTTP::Request` object explicitly and pass that to `LWP::UserAgent`'s `request()` method, but there is a `post()` convenience method which does all this for you.

The example here uses the `Content` parameter to set the content of the post body, and sets the `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers at the same time.

```
my $response = $ua->post($url,
    Content => $post_data,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    Authorization => $auth_header_value
);

die "Request failed: ", $response->content unless $response->is_success();

print $response->content, $/;
```

### Checking the response

It may be enough to check the LWP Response object as above - by invoking the `$response->is_success()` method. Nonetheless, if you want to explicitly check for success, just decode the JSON response - using `$resp = decode_json($response->decoded_content)`. Then examine the relevant keys in the resulting hash.

Comment: Hello, Thank You @David for your answer, but even after trying the code i get the below error: `{"Success":false,"Error":"Signature does not match request parameters."}`Please can you provide inputs on how can i solve this issue. It works when i test with Java code using the same Private key and Public key but it does not work with Perl.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the MIME::Base64 module does not automatically pad the output of `encode_base64()` to 4 bytes. See https://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/SHA.html#PADDING-OF-BASE64-DIGESTS for example.

Comment: Thank You @David . I tried doing `encode_base64(md5($post_data),' ');`Still it does not work:(.

Comment: Hi. No. That won't work. See solution on link above.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think it should work for you now. Note that the example uses the `GetTradeHistory` API call instead of `SubmitTrade` (which is probably safer during testing). You will want to modify the `%req` object and URL as appropriate.

Comment: Ok Thanks @David .

Comment: On further examination ... I think the issue with the Base64-encoding is not the 4-byte padding (or lack thereof) - but the fact that `encode_base64()` adds a newline to the output by default. Passing an empty string as the second parameter fixes this. (The updated code reflects this.)